# Update a series of random dates in a Postgres column

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, sql-update

I have a simple table in postgresql with two columns 
 "Profile_id" (text)
 policy_expires (date)[image: sample table]

The policy_expires column is empty (only null values).
I want to update that column with s series of dates.
I tried this query

```
insert into public.renewal_large ("policy_expires") 
select  generate_series('2020-07-01'::date,'2021-08-01'::date,'1 hour'::interval
```

it did create the series of dates i needed but it also created a null profile id value next to each new date.

[image: null profile id]

I am trying to figure out the correct query to update the existing profie_id column with the series of dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want an `update` statement rather than an `insert` - and presumably, you want different dates on each row (the time portion does not seem relevant, otherwise you would rather use a `timestamp` than a `date`).

If your `id`s are always increasing, you could just them for increment:

```
update renewal_large
set policy_expires = '2020-07-01'::date + (profile_id::int - 1) * interval '1' day
```

Otherwise, you can enumerate the rows with `row_number()`, then use it to compute the target date:

```
update renewal_large r
set policy_expires = '2020-07-01'::date + (r1.rn - 1) * interval '1' day
from (select id, row_number() over(order by id) rn from renewal_large) r1
where r1.id = r.id
```